# How to overlap a canvas circle over my drawimage and set cordinate and event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to set information on my Denmark map when I mouse-over a city. I tried drawing a circle but it wouldn't show up on my map (it appeared under, not over) and I'm not sure if you could set event to it. This is my first time using canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startCanvas() {
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

            //draw a circle
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(75, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();

            var image = new Image();

            image.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(image, 69, 50);
            };

            image.src = 'denmark.jpg';                 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="startCanvas()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600";">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what Derek means:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function startCanvas() {
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 69, 50);
            //draw a circle
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(75, 75, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
        };

        image.src = 'denmark.jpg';                 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startCanvas()">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600";">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it appeared under not over. You have to fill the circle AFTER you draw the image if you want it on top. Think about what those functions do to the pixel data (replacing pixels). You can draw the circle inside the same event, onload for the image, just draw it after the drawImage call.